# Inline documentation for SSIS packages

Tags: sql-server-2005, documentation, ssis

Is there a way to create an inline documentation (like javadocs) for SSIS packages? Or what other techniques do you use to document the things you develop for SQL Server 2005?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's pretty low-tech, but we put limited SSIS documentation in annotations within the package (right-click on any unoccupied portion of the design pane in the Control Flow, Data Flow or Error Handler tabs and select `Add Annotation`).

There's a limit to how much you can usefully put in these fields, particularly on complex packages, so detailed documentation goes into Word.

If there's a better way to add inline documentation, I'd love to know about it.

Comment: I found to pieces of software, which are both not for free, so I couldn't try them.
www.ssisdocumenter.com
http://www.apexsql.com/sql_tools_doc.asp